# When is the masculine "der" the English "of"?

Tags: definite-article

I have seen that in German, sometimes the definite masculine article "der" is used as the English word "of". For example in the film "Das Leben der Anderen". I understand this translates to "The lives of others". I would expect this to be, in German: "Das Leben von Anderen."

In what situations is "der" used in place of "von"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a misconception here. The word *der* has various roles. In the film title

> Das Leben *der* Anderen (genitive)

it is not the definite [masculine article *der*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel), but the genitive inflection of the definite [plural article *die*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/die#Artikel) (*die Anderen* is plural). A proper translation would be

> The life of *the* Others
>
> <sup>(Caution: It differs from the English film title *The Lives of Others*, which would be *Die Leben anderer* in German!)</sup>

where the German article *der* is reflected directly by the English article *the*. Notice, that in English the preposition *of* is used, which actually corresponds to the dative preposition *von* in German. In fact, the film title could be reworded with a dative instead of a genitive:

> Das Leben *von* den Anderen (dative)

But this sounds clumsy, which is why I think the author preferred the genitive version. I guess, this is different in English, where the genitive version "The Others’ life" would sound clumsy.

Comment: Maybe a remark about "of" roughly expressing what genitive case does to "die" would be helpful, as well. It is somewhat implied in the end, but in a rather roundabout way.

Comment: @guidot, *der* can be a lot of things (alone four inflection forms of certain definite articles, pronoun etc.). But I wouldn't want to list everything that it could potentially be, because it is irrelevant for this example in which *der* is only one particular thing: genitive inflection of the plural article *die*.

Answer (score 1):

*Of* has many meanings, a frequent one being the a direct translation of a genitive construct in German as in

> Der Reifen des Wagens (the tyre of the car)

Looking at the [Wiktionary table](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel) connected to definite articles, we observe, that in the genitive line *der* occurs at female singular and any plural. (*der* in other lines are not relevant, since they don't translate to *of*.)

So in all of the cases:

- das Hündchen **der** Nachbarin (fem. sing., the little dog of the [female] neighbour)
- die Trachten **der** Männer (masc. pl), **der** Frauen (fem. pl.), **der** Kinder (neuter pl.) translating to *traditional cosumes of the men/women/children*

*der* would translate to *of*.